# Ruby on Rails 7 with React integration

Tags: reactjs, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am new to Ruby on Rails and maybe this is a very trivial issue, but I searched online for a solution and all of them are at least 2-3 years old and they described the same thing. All the tutorials and videos I watched, said to create a new app with webpack for React, using:

```
rails new app_name --webpack=react -d=postgresql -T
```

Everybody said, that this command will create a pack folder under my app/javascript folder like this:

```
    app/javascript:
  └── packs:
      └── application.js
      └── hello_react.jsx
```

None of this actually happened. I do not have a pack folder. Instead, I have the following:

```
    app/javascript:
  └── controllers:
      └── application.js
      └── hello_controller.js
      └── index.js
```

So, what am I doing wrong? Why I do not have the pack folder and how can I integrate React with Ruby on Rails?
My environment is - Linux Manjaro XFCE 21.2.6, ruby 3.0.3, rails 7.0.2.4.

Comment: no `--webpack` command in rails 7. use https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker

Comment: I use the `webpacker` and `react-rails` gems  in my rails-react project (Rails 7.0.2.4) and it is working. Here is the repo at GitHub: https://github.com/Hombre2014/hello-rails-react

Comment: @Alex According to [this](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/42999) there still IS a `--webpack` option in Rails 7.  (It's possible that it doesn't work the same way, but that post seems to suggest that it does work the same way.)

Comment: @iconoclast it was later [removed](https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/43160/commits/c0fd560a020c6ec01d6a65827070c57c7e0b6b32) before 7 alpha release. now, there is `--javascript=webpack` option which sets up `jsbundling-rails` with webpack. which is a different setup from `webpacker`.

Comment: @Alex: ahhh, thanks for the clarification.  That's why I'm seeing so much incorrect information, since all the bloggers who want to appear to be on the cutting edge post their blog posts as soon as an alpha or beta version drops 

Answer (score 5):

In Rails 7, webpacker isn't the default choice anymore and [it has been replaced](https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b) by [import maps](https://github.com/rails/importmap-rails), so that's why any old rails/react tutorial won't work by default for this newer version.
If you're starting a new project and want to use the React framework, my suggestion is to simply search for [up-to-date Rails/React tutorials](https://www.google.com/search?q=rails%207%20react), as there are already plenty of them.
In case it's a project upgrading to Rails 7 and you don't want to get rid of `webpack`, you might consider to migrate to [`jsbundling-rails`](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails) or start using [`shakapacker`](https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker), which it seems to be from now the official successor of `webpacker`.
In `jsbundling-rails` project, [there's a comparison of both gems](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/main/docs/comparison_with_webpacker.md) to help you decide. Finally, there's a [`webpacker` -> `jsbundling-rails` guide](https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails/blob/main/docs/switch_from_webpacker.md) and a [`webpacker` -> `shakapacker` guide](https://github.com/shakacode/shakapacker/blob/master/docs/v6_upgrade.md) to help you with your transition when you have finally decided which one to use.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, the webpacker is gone and there are different ways to do this.

Comment: It seems that your answer might be true, but my question was more likely - Is it possible to use webpacker with Rails 7 and it seems that it is possible. I do not use `import maps`, nor `jsbuilding-rails` or `shakapacker`. I know that if you use those libraries you can make it and probably this is the way forward, but in my requirement, I had to use `webpacker` and `react-rails` gems. So, I created a new public repo on GitHub, where you can see it: https://github.com/Hombre2014/hello-rails-react It's working. Can you comment on this?

Comment: Webpacker is not "gone" in Rails 7, it is simply not the default option.  You can still use it if you want.  https://world.hey.com/dhh/rails-7-will-have-three-great-answers-to-javascript-in-2021-8d68191b

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong is your command. here is the proper command to generate a new Rails project to use webpack in Rails 7:

```
rails new app_name -j webpack
```

then you can add react.js with the following command:

```
yarn add react react-dom
```

you can find the documentation at https://github.com/rails/jsbundling-rails